# curl error : couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I am using localhost.So, Here i am getting error like curl error : couldn't connect to  host.Can anyone help?Thanks in advance

```
$postp="http://mainadmin.dove-sms.com/sendsms.jsp?user=username&password=password&mobiles=$mobilenumbers&sms=$message&unicode=1";
$ch = curl_init($postp);

$ret = array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1);
$ret1 = curl_setopt_array($ch, $ret);

$curlresponse = curl_exec($ch); 

if(curl_errno($ch))

echo 'curl error : '. curl_error($ch);
```

Comment: working fine here. can you resolve the host mainadmin.dove-sms.com?

Comment: By resolve what do u mean?When we give the inputs directly on api url it works,but when submitting input from html form it throws this error.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider is right, it Might be DNS error,

Comment: Could also be a firewall that blocks outgoing connections. I don't think the problem is in your code though.

Comment: You have SSL options set but are not connecting via SSL.

Comment: How to connect via SSL?

Comment: Change `http` to `https`.